# Process a string line by line and split the content into variables

Tags: php, regex

I need to get some data for each line of a big string in that way:

1. empty line should be ignored
2. If there is no `|` at all -> $content = $value
3. If there is one `|` -> first part will be $content, second part (if exisiting) will be $more
4. If there are two `|` -> text in the middle will be $content, last part will be $more

**example**

```
|text|
text
another|text|example

have fun|
text|more text
||
|just some keywords (25-50% )|
```

**result**

```
$content = 'text'   
$content = 'text'
$content = 'text'; $more = 'example'; $pre = 'another'
$content = 'have fun'
$content = 'text'; $more = 'more text'
$content = just some keywords (25-50% )'
```

So I tried to solve that thing with explode and if/else, but I failed with that:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
    if ($line != "") {
        $line_array = explode("|", $value);
        if(count($line_array) == 3) {
            // is '|anything|' or 'x|y|z'
        }
        else if (count($line_array) == 1) {
            // anything else
        }
    }
}
```

**regEx**

My attempt `(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)$` gets all lines which has two `|`, but not the other lines...

https://regex101.com/r/yW7oR3/5

Comment: This is pretty similar to your last regex question. Try some regexs and post your attempts.

Comment: I would like to create a regex, but it is too difficult for me, as the lines have very different format (for me). That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(?:^|^([^\|]+))\|?([^\|]+)\|?(?:$|([^\|]+)$)/gm` seems to work,
see https://regex101.com/r/yW7oR3/6 to test it.

I designed it like :

- $1 = $pre
- $2 = $content
- $3 = $more

Answer (score -2):

What was wrong with your "failed" approach?  Here it is with the missing code ...

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = trim($line)
    if ($line !== "") {
        $parts = explode("|", $line);
        if (count($parts)==1) {
            $content = $parts[0];
        } else if (count($parts)==2) {
            $content = $parts[0];
            $more = $parts[1];
        } else if (count($parts)==3) {
            $content = $parts[1];
            $more = $parts[2];
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid - more than 2 "|"';
        }
    }
}
```

This code follows your English description of the requirements.

Comment: Missing `;`, --> `$line = trim($line)`

Comment: My attempt is not wrong, but I think it is not very smart to use multiple if, insted of using one regEx, isn't it?

Comment: (Jeez, why the down votes?)  Regarding whether one regex is smarter than multiple-ifs, I guess it depends on what your goal is: magical or maintainable code.  Thomas' regex above is magical, I'm sure it's correct (I think), but it would take most readers of that code quite a while to understand it and even longer to maintain/update it for a new requirement.  The multiple-ifs, however, read almost like your written specs and, I believe, would be easier to maintain/update.  But that's just my humble opinion.  Please don't down vote me any more :)